# Articulate Scorm 2004 Cms compliance

Tags: scorm2004

I wrote a JavaScript file for launching Scorm courses; it's working good for Scorm 1.2. But in the case of Scorm 2004, 'Unable to find an API adapter' alert is coming when I launch my course.

Unable to locate the LMS's API Implementation. LMSInitialize was not successful. What changes need to be done in my JavaScript file to make my LMS work properly for Scorm 2004.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your JS code should look for `API_1484_11` object instead of  `API` object.
Second, you need to call SCORM 2004 API calls, for example Initialize, SetValue, GetValue instead of LMSInitialize, LMSSetValue, LMSGetValue.
Third, if your LMS does not support SCORM 2004, you need to upgrade your system to SCORM 2004.

Comment: Thanks ,Actually i changed my js code as u mentioned and all the data model changes mentioned in the Scorm 2004 documentation...i successfully launched some courses using Scorm 2004 package,for example course created using LECTORA....but its not working in the case of Articulate Scorm 2004...what changes must be done to make my CMS compatible with course created by Articulate using Scorm 2004...Please help me to fix it out....Regards ,Arun KG

Comment: Could you please send me your js code and the imsmanifest file? My email is: fadelms@naseelco.com. If your LMS recognized other SCORM 2004 courses, then the problem is either with the mainifest or the JS code.

Comment: Hi,I have mailed my JS file and manifest.Please look into it and suggest the changes needed for the code to work properly...Regards Arun KG

Comment: The manifest file and JS code are compatible with SCORM 2004. I'm afraid your LMS does not support SCORM 2004. You can do nothing about that unless you awnt to upgrade your system to a version which supports 2004.

Comment: Hi Fadel,
Thanks for helping me out.
Actually its my own LMS and there is no vendor.So when i upload a Scorm 1.2 its working properly and the code for that was created by me .So when the case of all Scorm 2004 its not working .There is addscormcourse.php file where i am doing all the things needed for scorm(xml parsing and  all).I am launching it from launchcourse.php where i include ths JS file which i mailed you earlier.If it is necessary i will mail you the the 2 files mentioned in the mail.....

Otherwise please tell me how can in upgrade my LMS to Scorm 2004...

Waiting for your reply...

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your LMS supports SCORM 2004 as well? You would see that error if you tried to deploy a 2004 course in a 1.2 environment.

Comment: Hi Mike,My LMS is not supporting Scorm 2004....its actually working for scorm 1.2 ....Will u please tell the modifications i have to do to make my LMS supporting Scorm 2004....'Unable to find an API adapter' alert is coming when i launch my course created in Scorm 2004...'Unable to locate the LMS's API Implementation.
LMSInitialize was not successful'....How can i fix this problem....

Comment: Hi Mike,Actually i wrote an javascript file for launching Scorm  courses...its working good for Scorm 1.2...But in the case of Scorm 2004 ...'Unable to find an API adapter' alert is coming when i launch my course....Unable to locate the LMS's API Implementation. LMSInitialize was not successful...What changes need to be done in my javascript file to make my LMS work properly for Scorm 2004....Its very urgent ....Please help me to fix the same....